# Which design pattern and SOLID principle to be applied if i have to display differnt message on for each item inside a Dynamic integer collection

Tags: c#, design-patterns

The Requirement is

1. I want to create  a dynamic Collection of integers which mean the IEnumerable collection can have 1 to 100 or 1 to 500 or 1 to 1000 integers.
2. I want to iterate through the collection and While iterating , i want to display different message each time on division of each item  by 3 or by 5 or by 7.

For Example:- in enumerable collection of integers of 1 to 100, when 3 is found which is divisible by 3, then 3 will be replaced with word "FUZZ" and so one like 6,9,12 will be replaced by "FUZZ"

When 5 is found which is divisible by 5, 5 will be replaced by word "BUZZ" and so as number 10,15(divisible by both 3 and 5 will be replaced by FUZZBIZZ and 20 will be replaced by word "BIZZ" again.

I want to implement logic for this , I think Strategy and Single responsibility principle will fit in this as i can have abstract interface strategy for Division by 3 and division by 5 and another interface for Display strategy of displaying "FUZZ" and "BIZZ" in two division scenarios.

Please correct me or guide me in Right design patterns and SOLID principle like SRP/Open closed principle of SOLID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

School assignment? I don't see why there's a need for design patterns for the given requirements, since it can be realized with just a few lines of code. Design patterns can be powerful, but should only be used when necessary.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach(var item in Generate(1, 1000))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>> Generate(int init, int max)
    {
        int current = init;

        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while (current <= max)
        {
            if (current % 3 == 0) stringBuilder.Append("FUZZ");
            if (current % 5 == 0) stringBuilder.Append("BIZZ");
            if (current % 7 == 0) stringBuilder.Append("????");

            yield return new KeyValuePair<int, string>(current, stringBuilder.ToString());
            stringBuilder.Clear();

            current++;
        }
    }
```

Sidenote: iterator pattern implemented by using the `foreach`, and the builder pattern by using `StringBuilder`. Both not implemented by myself though.